# Firebase Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My array is complete, but the index does not exist

Mi DB:

```
v_tableM='ad_modulo';
v_tableI='ad_permiso';
v_tableF='ad_persona';

const v_db=firebase.database().ref();
const v_child1=v_db.child('/'+v_tableM+'/');
const v_child2=v_db.child('/'+v_tableI+'/');
const v_child3=v_db.child('/'+v_tableF+'/');



v_child1.on('child_added', v_child1Snap=>{
  const v_child1Key=v_child1Snap.key;

  v_child2.child(v_child1Key).once('value', v_child2Snap=>{
    if (v_child2Snap.val() != null){
      v_child2SnapVal=v_child2Snap.val();
      const v_child2Key=v_child2Snap.key;
      if (v_child1Key==v_child2Key) {
        Object.keys(v_child2SnapVal).forEach(function (v_key) {
          v_child3.child(v_key).once('value', v_child3Snap=>{
            v_detail=[v_child2Key,v_key,v_child1Snap.val(),v_child3Snap.val()];
            v_result.push(v_detail);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

});

console.log(v_result);
```

Result in console:

```
[]
```

Click in array console:

```
[]
0: Array(4)
1: Array(4)
2: Array(4)
3: Array(4)
4: Array(4)
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Mi DB Json:

[image: DB JSON]

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowing the asynchronous function to complete before printing your variable. Read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) . I would call an asynchronous function and then print the array. For example,

```
var example_array = [];
exampleAsyncCall(example_array)
.then(function(example_array) {
  console.log(example_array);
});
```

And then inside your example function, you could say,

```
function exampleAsyncCall(v_result) {
return new promise((resolve, reject) {
    v_tableM = 'ad_modulo';
    v_tableI = 'ad_permiso';        
    v_tableF = 'ad_persona';
            const v_db = firebase.database().ref();
            const v_child1 = v_db.child('/' + v_tableM + '/');
            const v_child2 = v_db.child('/' + v_tableI + '/');
            const v_child3 = v_db.child('/' + v_tableF + '/');
            v_child1.on('child_added', v_child1Snap => {
                const v_child1Key = v_child1Snap.key;
                v_child2.child(v_child1Key).once('value', v_child2Snap => {
                    if (v_child2Snap.val() != null {
                            v_child2SnapVal = v_child2Snap.val();
                            const v_child2Key = v_child2Snap.key;
                            if (v_child1Key == v_child2Key {
                                    Object.keys(v_child2SnapVal).forEach(function(v_key) {
                                        v_child3.child(v_key).once('value', v_child3Snap => {
                                            v_detail = [v_child2Key, v_key, v_child1Snap.val(), v_child3Snap.val()];
                                            v_result.push(v_detail);
                                        });
                                    });
           resolve(v_result);
           //Resolve here, after the forEach loop has completed. 
                                }
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
        }
```

Sorry for messy code I'm doing this on mobile.

Comment: Thanks, modify the code and now I do so. Now it does not print anything in console.

Comment: If what you have is in your answer below, then you forgot to add the `resolve;` after your forEach loop. Please copy my code above again. @user3621571

Answer (score 0):

I modify the code, now it does not bring anything to me in console.

```
var example_array = [];
exampleAsyncCall(example_array).then(function(example_array) {
  console.log(example_array);
});

function exampleAsyncCall(v_result) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v_tableM='ad_modulo';
    v_tableI='ad_permiso';
    v_tableF='ad_persona';

    const v_db=firebase.database().ref();
    const v_child1=v_db.child('/'+v_tableM+'/');
    const v_child2=v_db.child('/'+v_tableI+'/');
    const v_child3=v_db.child('/'+v_tableF+'/');

    v_child1.on('child_added', function(v_child1Snap){

      const v_child1Key=v_child1Snap.key;
      const v_module = v_child1Snap.val();
      v_child2.child(v_child1Key).once('value', function(v_child2Snap){
        if (v_child2Snap.val() != null){
          const v_child2SnapVal=v_child2Snap.val();
          const v_child2Key=v_child2Snap.key;
          if (v_child1Key==v_child2Key) {
            v_child3.orderByKey().on('child_added', function(v_child3Snap){
              const v_child3Key=v_child3Snap.key;
              v_result.push(v_child1Key,v_child3Key,v_child1Snap.val(),v_child3Snap.val());
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please copy my code in my answer completely. You don't have a `resolve;` statement, which is necessary.